# D3 update x coordinate element

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Given a linear scale with domain `[0, 1]` and range `[0, window width]`, I would like to render `ticksNumber = 5` vertical lines equally spaced.

So, I created the array `ticksValues` that contains the lines `x` coordinates computed as `width * ticksValues[i]`.

Then I bind this array with the line DOM elements by index. What I would like to have is always 5 (or 6, depends by d3) lines equally spaced on the entire range that change because depends on the window width.

My code doesn't work, why? Seems like the data binding is not correct

```js
const ticksNumber = 5

window.addEventListener('resize', getWindowSize)
function getWindowSize() {
  var width = window.innerWidth
  var height = window.innerHeight

  const xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 1])
    .range([0, width])
  const ticksValues = xScale.ticks(ticksNumber).map(d => d * width)

  const svg = d3.select('#svg')
  const grid = svg.append('g')
  grid
    .selectAll('line')
    .data(ticksValues, (d, i) => i)
    .enter()
    .append('line')
    .attr('x1', d => d)
    .attr('x2', d => d)
    .attr('y1', 0)
    .attr('y2', height)
    .attr('stroke', 'red')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg id="svg"></svg>
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-satoshi-2qcfq?file=/index.html) a codesandbox.

Comment: One problem is that one new grid is added at each occurrence of the resize event, on top of the existing one(s)

Comment: `d * width` is likely not to produce the expected result for tick position, as it will position most ticks outside of the viewport. Instead of calculating coordinates by yourself, let `d3.scale` do it for you.

Comment: You should lookup about `debouncing` events, in order to avoid recalculating and re-displaying the grid all the time.

Comment: @Mehdi about `debouncing` and grid duplication, you are right, the above example is only a simple example. But what is the problem about data binding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. The merge selection was missing.

```
const grid = svg.append('g');
const update = grid.selectAll("line").data(ticksValues);
update.enter()
  .append("line")
  .merge(update)
  .attr("x1", d => this.xScale(d))
  .attr("x2", d => this.xScale(d))
  .attr("y1", 0)
  .attr("y2", height);
```

Answer (score 1):

One issue is that the lines' positions are defined according to the window's width, but the SVG's width is not set. Define an explicit `100%` width attribute to the SVG in order for all the lines to become displayed.

```
<svg id="svg" width="100%"></svg>
```

The last bar is going to be right at the limit of the viewport, hence not visible. Defining a margin fixes this problem. Example:

```
const margin = 50
var width = window.innerWidth - margin
```

[This article](https://observablehq.com/@d3/margin-convention) shows good practices regarding margins in d3.

The formula used to compute position of lines seems correct. However, it is no necessary to bother with these details, as `d3-scale` does it for us.

```
let dataset = d3.range(ticksNumber) // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

xScale.domain(d3.extent(dataset))

// ... 

selection.append('line')
  .attr('x1', d => xScale(d))
  // ...
```

Demo of this set of fixes in the snippet below.

Other issues with the sample code, not solved in this demo.

- a new grid of line is added on top of the existing ones each time the window is resized. Instead, the bars should be drawn once at page load. Then on resize, their `x` positions should be shifted.
- performance: window resize event listener should be debounced.

```js
const ticksNumber = 5
  , margin = 50
  , dataset = d3.range(ticksNumber)


getWindowSize()

function getWindowSize() {
  var width = window.innerWidth - margin
  var height = window.innerHeight

  const xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain(d3.extent(dataset))
    .range([0, width])
  
  const svg = d3.select('#svg')
  const grid = svg.append('g')
  grid
    .selectAll('line')
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append('line')
    .attr('x1', d => xScale(d))
    .attr('x2', d => xScale(d))
    .attr('y1', 0)
    .attr('y2', height)
    .attr('stroke', 'red')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg id="svg" width="100%"></svg>
```

Comment: Thanks but also your lines do not change position when window is resized

Comment: Anyway, thank you @Mehdi, I didn't know `range()` function, very useful!

Comment: Yes, the demo only shows how to fix the "lines not displayed" problem.